# Will an SSD and more RAM increase VM performance?

Tags: memory, ssd

I have a macbook since December 2011.

This is my configuration:

- MacBook Pro (13-inch, Late 2011)
- Processor 2.4 GHz Intel Core i5
- Memory 4 GB 1333 MHz DDR3
- Graphics Intel HD Graphics 3000 384 MB

I going to buy this [SSD](http://www.rue-montgallet.com/prix/acheter,crucial-250go-mx200,805797) and this [RAM](http://www.rue-montgallet.com/prix/acheter,crucial-so-dimm-mac-ddr3-1600-cl11-8go,771153)

I have 2 question:

- I'm pretty sure, that the SSD and the RAM are compatible with my computer, but does anyone can confirm me I made the right choice please.
- I need to install many OS on a virtual machine, but sometime, it could be impossible to install or used it because it was too slow. Does anyone can confirm me if the SSD + more RAM will increase my VM performance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on a couple of factors:

- Does your MacBook already have an SSD?
- Are you using your VMs for disk and memory-intensive operations?

In general, yes, an SSD and more memory will speed up VMs.  For me, switching to SSD provided a greater performance benefit than any other single upgrade I've ever done.

If your MacBook already has SSD, a newer/bigger/faster SSD isn't going to make much difference.

RAM will only make a difference if it gets used, which depends entirely on how much you have, how much is allocated to the VMs, what operating systems they will have, and what programs you run in the VMs.  4 GB sounds like not much RAM to be using VMs, especially if you're trying to run more than one at a time.

Comment: Hello, my macbook doesn't have a SSD yet, I don't use memory-intensive operations, I only used emacs and some compiler.
Could you please confirm me that I made an adapted choice about the SSD and RAM I would like to buy ? Thanks

Comment: Assuming you've selected one that has sufficient capacity for your needs (it's impossible to tell from the info you've provided), the brand of SSD isn't nearly as relevant as the fact that it's an SSD.  Any SSD from any major manufacturer will outperform the HDD in your MacBook by a wide margin. I'd start with the SSD and see if that does the trick before spending more on RAM too, unless you've got some really good holiday deal.